# PHP smtp не получается отправить почту на оду и ту же доменную почту

Tags: php, smtp

Столкнулся с проблемой.

Не могу отправить почту. Пример `hello@domain.kz`, на почту `user_name@domain.kz`.

Отправляю на любую другую почту, все работает.

Использую библиотеку `PHPmailer`.

Такое возможно сделать?

Comment: это локально или на хосте?

Comment: Да, на хосте. Да и какая разница. С локалки тоже работает. Не привык раскрывать название, где и что.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107730/cant-send-email-to-addresses-at-my-own-domain

Comment: Проверьте наличие ошибки у PHPMailer после отправки письма: ```$mail = new PHPMailer; .... if (!$mail->Send()) { echo $mail->ErroInfo; }```